# how to build complex array with questions and answers? - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have:

```
var answers = [];

                var frage1 = document.getElementById("frage1").innerHTML;
                frage1antwort1 = $('#frage1antwort1:checked').length; f.Example Value = 0
                frage1antwort2 = $('#frage1antwort2:checked').length; f.Example Value = 0
                frage1antwort3 = $('#frage1antwort3:checked').length; f.Example Value = 1

                var frage2 = document.getElementById("frage2").innerHTML;
                frage2antwort1 = $('#frage2antwort1:checked').length; f.Example Value = 0
                frage2antwort2 = $('#frage2antwort2:checked').length; f.Example Value = 0
                frage2antwort3 = $('#frage2antwort3:checked').length; f.Example Value = 1

                var frage3 = document.getElementById("frage3").innerHTML;
                frage3antwort1 = $('#frage3antwort1:checked').length; f.Example Value = 1
                frage3antwort2 = $('#frage3antwort2:checked').length; f.Example Value = 0
                frage3antwort3 = $('#frage3antwort3:checked').length; f.Example Value = 0

                var frage4 = document.getElementById("frage4").innerHTML;
                frage4antwort1 = $('#frage4antwort1:checked').length; f.Example Value = 0
                frage4antwort2 = $('#frage4antwort2:checked').length; f.Example Value = 1
                frage4antwort3 = $('#frage4antwort3:checked').length; f.Example Value = 0 

                var frage5 = document.getElementById("frage5").innerHTML;
                frage5antwort1 = $('#frage5antwort1:checked').length; f.Example Value = 0
                frage5antwort2 = $('#frage5antwort2:checked').length; f.Example Value = 1
                frage5antwort3 = $('#frage5antwort3:checked').length; f.Example Value = 0
```

i am trying to build an array with questions and selected answer for it. nothing is right by me.
as result [Question=1, Answer= 3], something like that. please help!

Comment: I don't see where you actually push values onto the `answers` array.

Comment: all my ideas are wrong, and its not working. i hope for some clean solutions from you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you trying arrays ? you can do the same easily with objects.

please check http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

for Example

```
function question(que,ans1,ans2,ans3)
{
this.question=que;
this.answer1=ans1;
this.answer2=ans2;
this.answer3=ans3;
}
```

and then

```
var frage1=new question(document.getElementById("frage1").innerHTML, $('#frage1antwort1:checked').length,$('#frage1antwort2:checked').length,$('#frage1antwort3:checked').length);
```

you just need to define question object then create new objects or assign the values and grab whenever required.

This will give you clear idea [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: you just need to define question object then create new objects or assign the values and grab whenever required.

Comment: thank you it works well! can i save all 5 question in one object which i can build as a result for responce??

Comment: it will be easy if you create an array of 5 question object :)

Comment: yes i did it like this:  function surveyResultFull(frage1, frage2, frage3, frage4, frage5) {
            this.frage1 = frage1;
            this.frage2 = frage2;
            this.frage3 = frage3;
            this.frage4 = frage4;
            this.frage5 = frage5;
        }

Comment: and filling it here:  var frage5 = new surveyResult(document.getElementById("frage5").innerHTML, $('#frage5antwort1:checked').length, $('#frage5antwort2:checked').length, $('#frage5antwort3:checked').length);

                var result = surveyResultFull(frage1, frage2, frage3, frage4, frage5);